# How should I ordered my SQLite services in Flutter? All-in-one or one per table?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, sqflite

Recently I have started to develop an app in Flutter, and I have some questions about SQLite and the use on Flutter. I have a database connected to the app with SQLite. It has different tables relationed between them, and I have a main service called `user-service` where I load the main user when the app starts running. I initialize the database in its constructor.

Question is about that. If a want to have another service... How should I create that service?

1. Passing dbHelper from UserService as a parameter in the constructor? (to avoid initialize it again)
2. Without passing dbHelper. I mean, initialize again dbHelper.
3. Forget different services and create all queries from all data in only one service.

Thanks for answer me!

Comment: Thats where  state management like provider comes into play.  Use provider  to do this easily. You can access the databse anywhere in any screen. (Anywhere in the tree)

Comment: I haven't use any pattern to develop the app. I see provider and BLoC as one of them, but I really don't understand them. Could you share a tutorial or something to undertand? Thanks!

Comment: Plenty of tutorials on youtube. But tutorial will not help until you implement it in real world. You can see my code at github. I have also used sqflite and I'm accessing it in almost every screen. `https://github.com/ProblematicDude/flutter-notes` Check here.